# Finding a constant that satisfies a given inequality

Tags: arithmetic

I have a problem where I was able to show via a series of steps, and Jensen's inequality, that

$x > y$ where $x>0$ and $y>0$. Since $x$ is always greater than $y$, is there anyway to multiply $x$ by a non-negative constant such that $x$ will always be less than $y$, i.e, I want to find a $\beta$ such that

$\beta x < y$ for $\beta >0$.

Comment: Do you mind adding your work in those steps

Comment: @Arjun They're not consequential to the question and are more in depth than just $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\beta$ just needs to be less than $y/x$,

i.e.,

$\beta < \frac{y}{x}$